# Assigning to global variable inside a function doesn't work

Tags: python

I'm newbie in Python programming and have a problem with global variables.
I have a code like this:

```
import ...
```

sentiment_words = {} #global variable

def getTweetSentiment(tweet_text):
    sentiment = 0
    words = extractWordsFromTweet(tweet_text)
    for word in words:
        if word in sentiments_words:
            sentiment += sentiments_words[word] #sentiment_words is empty
    return sentiment

def main():
    global sentiment_words
    sentiment_words = loadSentiments(open(sys.argv[1])) #setting new value

When I call `getTweetSentiment` function it doesn't see any variables inside `sentiment_words`. Could you please help me to understand how it should be written in right way?

Comment: Where is `loadSentiments` defined? Have you tried to `print sentiment_words` to see what's in it? Have you considered **not** using `global`, and having explicit parameters instead?

Comment: If you want to keep using it as a global variable, you need to globalise it right a the start (after imports)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use class. It's better than using global variable.

You can access to sentiment_words this way `sentimentTweet.sentiment_words`.

Your code would look like:

```
class sentimentTweet:
    def __init__(self,d={}):
        sentiment_words = d

    def getTweetSentiment(self,tweet_text):
        sentiment = 0
        words = extractWordsFromTweet(tweet_text)
        for word in words:
            if word in self.sentiments_words:
                sentiment += self.sentiments_words[word] #sentiment_words is empty
        return sentiment

sTwitter= sentimentTweet(loadSentiments(open(sys.argv[1]))) #u r creating an instance of the class and loading it 
print sTwitter.sentiment_words #Check, Try to print sentiment_words values
```

In case you have a tweet text. You can run your function `getTweetSentiment` this way.

```
t= "tweet_text" #I'm not sure how do you use this variable    
returnedSentiment= sTwitter.getTweetSentiment(t) #This is how you run your function
print t
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually calling the `main()` function at any point? From the code you've provided, it doesn't look like you are, which means that `loadSentiments()` will not be run and thus `sentiment_words` will remain unchanged (i.e. it will remain defined as `{}`).

Unlike C/C++/Java, Python programs do not start with a `main()` function/method. Instead, the program is run from the first line to the last, so you'll need to add the following at the bottom of your file:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This will ensure that the `main()` function is called if the file is executed directly.

Comment: Thanks for help. I already have this part of code. Just skip it for minimalism. After Java all this Python stuff is a bit tricky for me.